# Propagate Windows RDP Enablecredsspsupport Settings Across Domain

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

How do I disable the Enablecredsspsupport on a domain wide setting instead of going to every user to disable it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set it through [Group Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204773(v=vs.85).aspx), under *Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Credentials Delegation*.

(Alternatively, custom registry settings could also be pushed via the new "Preferences" feature in Group Policy, … I think it's a Server 2008 thing?)